# Do the Feynman diagrams where a line starts where it ends have a name?

Tags: terminology, feynman-diagrams

Do Feynman diagrams that have at least one line/propogator that begins and ends on the same space-time point have a special name? For example, the ["cactus" diagram](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/179574/problem-understanding-the-symmetry-factor-in-a-feynman-diagram) from the bottom of page 92 in ["An Introduction to Quantum Field Theory" by Peskin and Schroeder](https://westviewpress.com/books/an-introduction-to-quantum-field-theory/) qualifies. These are the diagrams that will have factors of $G(0)$ in them, where $G\left(\tau = \sqrt{\left(c\Delta t\right)^2 - \left|\Delta \vec{r}\right|^2}\right)$ is the [propagator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Propagator).

I ask because it seems that calling them [ouroboros](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ouroboros) diagrams, for the snake that eats its own tail, would be fittingly poetic, but am unsure if this or another name had already been coined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe in Mike Stone's [The Physics of Quantum Fields](https://books.google.com/books?id=lFXSBwAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&dq=physics%20of%20quantum%20fields&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiUtICo6K_WAhUp7YMKHTaHDroQ6AEIKDAA#v=onepage&q=ouroboros&f=false) they are called just that.