# Symmetry factor in Srednicki?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, symmetry, feynman-diagrams

The following diagram is given in Srednicki pg62 figure 9.7:

[image]

Srednicki gives this diagram a symmetry factor of $S=2^2=4$. But using a method which seems to work on every other diagram I get $S=2$ (the method is given below). Am I missing a subtly here or is the symmetry factor given in the book wrong?

> **My Method**
>
> We split each of the vertices into 3 and count the number of ways we can draw each line between two vertices (as shown below):
>   [image]
>   The number in front of the brackets gives the number of ways whilst the number in brackets gives the order which I chose them. On top of this we have a factor of $^4C_2 \times 2$ for swapping the $4$ vertices (taking into account that two vertices are identical). This thus gives us a symmetry factor of:
>   $$S^{-1}=\frac{3\times 3\times 6 \times 6\times 2 \times 2 \times 1}{(3!)^4 \times 4!} \times{^4C_2}\times 2$$
>   $$=\frac{3\times 3\times 6 \times 6\times 2 \times 2 \times 1}{(3!)^4 \times 4!} \frac{4!}{2!2!}\times 2$$
>   $$=1/2$$
>   Thus $S=2$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are right. You are basically using method 1) from my answer to [Problem understanding the symmetry factor in a feynman diagram](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/179574/problem-understanding-the-symmetry-factor-in-a-feynman-diagram) and you handled it like a champ. If you use method 2) from that same answer you will also find there is only one nontrivial automorphism. Think of the graph as a "theta" taking a nap on a hammock attached to the axis given by the two external legs. This autmorphism is the rotation by 180 degrees around this axis.

PS: If you have seen two-stage experiments in elementary probability or more general counting methods based on decision trees, then this is basically what you are doing. I recommend to *first* choose the vertices: 4 choices for the neighbor of the left external leg times 3 choices for the right leg neighbor, *and then* looking at the internal line contraction count. Of course $4\times 3={}^{4}C_{2}\times 2$.

---

**Edit as per AFT's comment:** The above answer is based on the assumption that one is computing a two-point function rather than a vacuum diagram. Note that the issue of symmetry factors is a question that belongs to mathematics rather physics. The proper setting for handling these factors with rigor and accuracy is Joyal's theory of combinatorial species: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combinatorial_species . You can see how one can apply it to the specific context of Feynman diagrams in my article ["Feynman Diagrams in Algebraic Combinatorics"](https://www.emis.de/journals/SLC/wpapers/s49abdess.html). The article focuses on a complex bosonic model with $\bar{\phi}\phi^n$ interaction but it is straightforward to transpose it to that of a real scalar $\phi^3$ model as in the OP's question.

Comment: The symmetry factor in Srednicki is correct -- it is indeed $S=4$. This is easily confirmed by a straightforward computation in, say, Mathematica. Note that Srednicki takes external vertices to be unlabelled, so you must account for permutations thereof. Perhaps this factor of $2$ is what you (and OP) are missing. If you feel like it, expand the path integral explicitly, and check for yourself that the diagram carries a factor of $4$. If you expand the two-point function, it will carry a factor of $2$. This is because the diagrams in the latter have labelled leaves, unlike those in the former.

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform: I see. Srednicki does something a bit nonstandard which is: he computes vacuum diagrams of a theory with both $\phi^3$ and $\phi$ vertices. This indeed results in a symmetry factor $S=4$ because the two $1$-valent vertices on the left and right sides of the diagram are treated as internal. My answer was based on the assumption that one is trying to compute a two point function $\langle\phi(x_1)\phi(x_2)\rangle$ which gives $S=2$ because the counted automorphisms have to keep the external legs fixed.

Comment: +1 Now I agree with your answer. In the chapter OP is reading, Srednicki is explaining how to calculate the partition function $Z[j]$. At that point, leaves are indistinguishable and therefore you must take into account permutations thereof. When you start taking functional derivatives $\frac{\delta}{\delta j_1}\cdots \frac{\delta}{\delta j_n}$ to compute the $n$-point function, the leaves acquire a labelling (from $1$ to $n$), and therefore the automorphism group contains isomorphisms that fix the external labels only.

Answer (score -1):

TL;DR: Srednicki is in the source-picture/$J$-picture where each external leg of a Feynman diagram is connected to a $J$-source, which is denoted by a fat black bullet. The caption of Fig. 9.7 says that there are $E=2$ external legs and $V=4$ vertices. Since the two $J$-sources are identical, that yields another $\mathbb{Z}_2$-automorphism, bringing the total symmetry factor to $S=4$.

References:

1. M. Srednicki, *QFT, 2007;* Fig. 9.7. A prepublication draft PDF file is available [here](http://web.physics.ucsb.edu/%7Emark/qft.html).