# Computing symmetry/combinatorial factor for a diagram in $\phi^4$ theory

Tags: homework-and-exercises, quantum-field-theory, symmetry, feynman-diagrams, perturbation-theory

I am working with $\lambda\phi^4/4!$ theory and am struggling to compute the symmetry factor for the diagram
[image]
by using the method specified [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/181081/219131). I know that the answer is ${1}/{12}$, but I can't work out how to get this.

Here is my reasoning:
[image]

> 0. the vertices are indistinguishable, so there is a factor of $3!$
> 1. 4 ways of choosing which leg of $u$ to connect to $x$
> 2. 4 ways of choosing which leg of $z$ to connect to $y$
> 3. 3 ways of choosing a leg of $u$ to connect to $z$, and 3 ways of choosing which leg of $z$ it should be connected to
> 4. 4 choices for connecting the first leg of $u$ to a leg of $w$
> 5. 3 choices for connecting the second leg of $u$ to the remaining legs of $w$
> 6. 2 ways to connect one of the last two legs of $w$ to $z$
> 7. 1 way to connect the final leg of $w$ to the final leg of $z$
>
> The overall factor is then (with a factor of ${1}/{4!^3 3!}$ from the Dyson expansion)
> $$ 
> \frac{1}{S} = \frac{1}{3!\cdot (4!)^3} \cdot 3! \cdot 4\cdot 4 \cdot 3 \cdot 3 \cdot 4 \cdot 3 \cdot 2 \cdot 1 = \frac{4^2 \cdot 3^2}{4!^2} = \frac{1}{4}.
> $$

I would be very grateful if anyone could point out where I have gone wrong. Alternatively, if anyone could explain another systematic way to compute symmetry factors for general Feynman diagrams then that would also be very helpful!

Comment: Step 3 carries a factor of $3.3=9$ so there are actually three 3's overall. Of course I have gone wrong somewhere though, so this may not be correct!

Comment: I apologize. I misread your post. I've deleted my comment. I seem to agree with your calculation. Who/what is telling you that the result must be 1/12?

Comment: No problem! Thank you for your help. It turns out that the source I was looking at (solutions to a problem set for a course I'm taking) was actually incorrect - $1/4$ is the right answer after all.

Comment: FWIW, the symmetry factor is $S=8$ ($S=4$) if the external legs are  indistinguishable (distinguishable), respectively.

Comment: @Qmechanic To clarify, do you agree with my calculation or have I gone wrong somewhere?

Comment: Sources screw up symmetry factors all the time, especially if they're written by people who never do concrete calculations... I once saw a book written by a distinguished string theorist. It had a dedicated section for symmetry factors, and 5 of the 7 examples were completely wrong.

Comment: It looks like you understand the general method, and once you know that, there's nothing else to it. Just trust yourself!